# How to test if google maps function runs on componentDidUpdate() with Jest + Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, jestjs, enzyme

I'm still new to TDD with Jest and Enzyme and have run into a problem trying to test my google map component.

The component receives GeoJson data as props from my API which is subject to change, so the init function should run on componentDidUpdate()

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Map extends Component {
    initMap = () => {
        const el = document.getElementById("map-js");

        const options = {
            center: {
                lat: -27.9959656,
                lng: 153.2879044,
            },
            zoom: 9
        };

        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(el, options);
        map.data.addGeoJson(this.props.data);
    };

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.initMap();
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="map__holder">
                <div id="map-js"></div>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default Map;
```

I am trying to write a test to check if the initMap function runs successfully if props are changed.

I wasn't sure the best way to pass props to my shallow render so I just used the first value from my Json file. Below is my test.

When I run this I keep getting this error "    TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined   "

Can anyone offer any advice on getting this test to pass?

Map.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Map from '../Map';

it("runs init map on component update", () => {
    const props = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "totalFeatures": 1,
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "af1b8d1c_a186_4e72_8e9e_549a8065e970.1",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485],
                            [153.29240999654635, -27.897600934719307],
                            [153.29243164508424, -27.897612892477547],
                            [153.29242807749804, -27.89762571619733],
                            [153.2924182348173, -27.897642434997323],
                            [153.29240518208437, -27.89764887031301],
                            [153.29238402481764, -27.897632940370542],
                            [153.29236010912982, -27.897619001393466],
                            [153.29233897564296, -27.8976119164061],
                            [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geom",
            "properties": {
                "rec_id": 1598139,
                "status": "CURRENT",
                "asset_numb": "BOAR320",
                "type": "Boat Ramp",
                "material": "Gravel",
                "number_lan": 1,
                "add_improv": "f",
                "top_rl": 0,
                "toe_rl": 0,
                "area_": 36.079,
                "comments": "Council use only",
                "documents": "../photos/31/j31p6.jpg",
                "inspectors": null,
                "inspection": "2009-09-23Z",
                "constructi": null,
                "record_cre": "2007-04-27Z",
                "last_updat": null,
                "update_dat": "2011-07-22Z",
                "disposal_d": null,
                "positional": "GPS Corrected 1.0M",
                "level_accu": null,
                "owner": "251",
                "project_nu": null,
                "file_numbe": null,
                "folder_num": null,
                "drawing_nu": null,
                "survey_num": null,
                "condition": 4,
                "historic_c": 0,
                "funding_ba": "Non GCCC",
                "mi_symbolo": "Pen (2, 2, 65535) Brush (1, 0, 16777215)",
                "mi_prinx": 1598139,
                "createuser": null,
                "createdate": null,
                "updateuser": null,
                "updatedate": null,
                "shape_leng": 25.1301720763,
                "shape_area": 36.0791723381
            }
        }]
    };

    const updatedProps = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "totalFeatures": 2, //value changed in updated props
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "af1b8d1c_a186_4e72_8e9e_549a8065e970.1",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485],
                            [153.29240999654635, -27.897600934719307],
                            [153.29243164508424, -27.897612892477547],
                            [153.29242807749804, -27.89762571619733],
                            [153.2924182348173, -27.897642434997323],
                            [153.29240518208437, -27.89764887031301],
                            [153.29238402481764, -27.897632940370542],
                            [153.29236010912982, -27.897619001393466],
                            [153.29233897564296, -27.8976119164061],
                            [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geom",
            "properties": {
                "rec_id": 1598139,
                "status": "CURRENT",
                "asset_numb": "BOAR320",
                "type": "Boat Ramp",
                "material": "Gravel",
                "number_lan": 1,
                "add_improv": "f",
                "top_rl": 0,
                "toe_rl": 0,
                "area_": 36.079,
                "comments": "Council use only",
                "documents": "../photos/31/j31p6.jpg",
                "inspectors": null,
                "inspection": "2009-09-23Z",
                "constructi": null,
                "record_cre": "2007-04-27Z",
                "last_updat": null,
                "update_dat": "2011-07-22Z",
                "disposal_d": null,
                "positional": "GPS Corrected 1.0M",
                "level_accu": null,
                "owner": "251",
                "project_nu": null,
                "file_numbe": null,
                "folder_num": null,
                "drawing_nu": null,
                "survey_num": null,
                "condition": 4,
                "historic_c": 0,
                "funding_ba": "Non GCCC",
                "mi_symbolo": "Pen (2, 2, 65535) Brush (1, 0, 16777215)",
                "mi_prinx": 1598139,
                "createuser": null,
                "createdate": null,
                "updateuser": null,
                "updatedate": null,
                "shape_leng": 25.1301720763,
                "shape_area": 36.0791723381
            }
        }]
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<Map data={props} />);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'initMap');

    wrapper.setProps({data: updatedProps});

    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the mocked `google` variable to `window` before running the test.

E.g.

`Map.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Map extends Component {
  initMap = () => {
    const el = document.getElementById('map-js');
    const options = {
      center: {
        lat: -27.9959656,
        lng: 153.2879044,
      },
      zoom: 9,
    };

    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(el, options);
    map.data.addGeoJson(this.props.data);
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="map__holder">
        <div id="map-js"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

`Map.test.js`:

```js
import Map from './Map';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('64635170', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const props = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      totalFeatures: 1,
      features: [
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          id: 'af1b8d1c_a186_4e72_8e9e_549a8065e970.1',
          geometry: {
            type: 'MultiPolygon',
            coordinates: [
              [
                [
                  [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485],
                  [153.29240999654635, -27.897600934719307],
                  [153.29243164508424, -27.897612892477547],
                  [153.29242807749804, -27.89762571619733],
                  [153.2924182348173, -27.897642434997323],
                  [153.29240518208437, -27.89764887031301],
                  [153.29238402481764, -27.897632940370542],
                  [153.29236010912982, -27.897619001393466],
                  [153.29233897564296, -27.8976119164061],
                  [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485],
                ],
              ],
            ],
          },
          geometry_name: 'geom',
          properties: {
            rec_id: 1598139,
            status: 'CURRENT',
            asset_numb: 'BOAR320',
            type: 'Boat Ramp',
            material: 'Gravel',
            number_lan: 1,
            add_improv: 'f',
            top_rl: 0,
            toe_rl: 0,
            area_: 36.079,
            comments: 'Council use only',
            documents: '../photos/31/j31p6.jpg',
            inspectors: null,
            inspection: '2009-09-23Z',
            constructi: null,
            record_cre: '2007-04-27Z',
            last_updat: null,
            update_dat: '2011-07-22Z',
            disposal_d: null,
            positional: 'GPS Corrected 1.0M',
            level_accu: null,
            owner: '251',
            project_nu: null,
            file_numbe: null,
            folder_num: null,
            drawing_nu: null,
            survey_num: null,
            condition: 4,
            historic_c: 0,
            funding_ba: 'Non GCCC',
            mi_symbolo: 'Pen (2, 2, 65535) Brush (1, 0, 16777215)',
            mi_prinx: 1598139,
            createuser: null,
            createdate: null,
            updateuser: null,
            updatedate: null,
            shape_leng: 25.1301720763,
            shape_area: 36.0791723381,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    const updatedProps = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      totalFeatures: 2, //value changed in updated props
      features: [
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          id: 'af1b8d1c_a186_4e72_8e9e_549a8065e970.1',
          geometry: {
            type: 'MultiPolygon',
            coordinates: [
              [
                [
                  [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485],
                  [153.29240999654635, -27.897600934719307],
                  [153.29243164508424, -27.897612892477547],
                  [153.29242807749804, -27.89762571619733],
                  [153.2924182348173, -27.897642434997323],
                  [153.29240518208437, -27.89764887031301],
                  [153.29238402481764, -27.897632940370542],
                  [153.29236010912982, -27.897619001393466],
                  [153.29233897564296, -27.8976119164061],
                  [153.29237339772322, -27.897575560605485],
                ],
              ],
            ],
          },
          geometry_name: 'geom',
          properties: {
            rec_id: 1598139,
            status: 'CURRENT',
            asset_numb: 'BOAR320',
            type: 'Boat Ramp',
            material: 'Gravel',
            number_lan: 1,
            add_improv: 'f',
            top_rl: 0,
            toe_rl: 0,
            area_: 36.079,
            comments: 'Council use only',
            documents: '../photos/31/j31p6.jpg',
            inspectors: null,
            inspection: '2009-09-23Z',
            constructi: null,
            record_cre: '2007-04-27Z',
            last_updat: null,
            update_dat: '2011-07-22Z',
            disposal_d: null,
            positional: 'GPS Corrected 1.0M',
            level_accu: null,
            owner: '251',
            project_nu: null,
            file_numbe: null,
            folder_num: null,
            drawing_nu: null,
            survey_num: null,
            condition: 4,
            historic_c: 0,
            funding_ba: 'Non GCCC',
            mi_symbolo: 'Pen (2, 2, 65535) Brush (1, 0, 16777215)',
            mi_prinx: 1598139,
            createuser: null,
            createdate: null,
            updateuser: null,
            updatedate: null,
            shape_leng: 25.1301720763,
            shape_area: 36.0791723381,
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const map = { data: { addGeoJson: jest.fn() } };
    const google = { maps: { Map: jest.fn(() => map) } };
    window.google = google;
    document.getElementById = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('el');
    const wrapper = shallow(<Map data={props}></Map>);
    const initMapSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'initMap');
    wrapper.setProps({ data: updatedProps });
    expect(initMapSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(document.getElementById).toBeCalledWith('map-js');
    expect(google.maps.Map).toBeCalledWith('el', {
      center: {
        lat: -27.9959656,
        lng: 153.2879044,
      },
      zoom: 9,
    });
    expect(map.data.addGeoJson).toBeCalledWith(updatedProps);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64635170/Map.test.js (10.908s)
  64635170
    ✓ should pass (9ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 Map.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.063s
```

Comment: Cheers buddy, that should do it